# ASP.NET web API related table data

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, entity-framework, c#-5.0

I'm building a angular web app with WEB API 2 as my data service.

Please see below scenario.

I have three tables
User
Company ( has foreign key of UserID and CompanyID)
Company Contact Details - ( has foreign key of CompanyID)

I have a form that needs to receive and update the data back to these three tables in one request. What is the best and cleanest way to do that ?

I could use the Entity Framework ALLINCLUDING method to link userRepo to the company Repo however i wont able to link the Company Contact Details repo due to it's not linked to the user table.

Any ideas ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is using a transaction.

Something like: `context.Database.BeginTransaction`.

See this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456843.aspx).